# Logback rolling logging not working

Tags: java, spring, logging, logback

I am trying to create logger policy in a spring based project.

The issue I am facing is related to rolling policy. the `logfile.log` is created and is working fine but the rolling file `rollingfile.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log` is not created.

Given below is my `logback.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
    <property name="LOG_PATH" value="D:/coinLogs" />
    <property name="LOG_ARCHIVE" value="${LOG_PATH}/archive" />

    <appender name="Console-Appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout>
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] - [%X{requestId}] - %p %c -- %m%n</pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="File-Appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/logfile.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] - [%X{requestId}] - %p %c -- %m%n
            </pattern>
            <outputPatternAsHeader>true</outputPatternAsHeader>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ARCHIVE}/rollingfile.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>


    <logger name="coinPay.logbackxml" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Console-Appender" />
        <appender-ref ref="File-Appender" />
    </logger>

    <!-- To remove extra hibernate logs -->
    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="Console-Appender" />
        <appender-ref ref="File-Appender" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender` as class for your appender. A FileAppender can not roll.

Comment: replace this <appender name="File-Appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender"> by this <appender name="File-Appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

Comment: After trying above changes even 'logfile.log' is not working. Is there anything else which also has to be changed ?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Maybe your log level is not appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing the **%i** parameter, which should be replaced by the rolling file index (i.e. 'mylog.2017-03-13.**0**.txt', 'mylog.2017-03-13.**1**.txt', etc.)

In addition, like *Uwe Allner*, I'm using RollingFileAppender instead of FileAppender.
(I also suggest adding a totalSizeCap to the configuration, in order to control to total size)

Here's my entire appender configuration:

```
<appender name="SQL_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_HOME}/mylog.txt</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level- %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <maxHistory>3</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>5GB</totalSizeCap>
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/archived/mylog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.txt.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```